# Lodash - search array of nested objects and return index

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

I have an array of nested objects. I'm trying to use Lodash to find the index of the parent object whose child object has a property (ariaSelected) set to true.

```
this.tabs = [
    {
        nativeElement: {
            ariaChecked: null
            ariaColCount: null,
            ariaSelected: false
        }
    },
    {
        nativeElement: {
            ariaChecked: null
            ariaColCount: null,
            ariaSelected: true
        }
    }   
]
```

This is what I'm trying to do, but it is not working

```
let currentTab = _.findIndex(this.tabs, 
    {
        nativeElement: {ariaSelected: true}
    }
);
```

Any help is very appreciated! :-)

Comment: You expect the index to be 1, right? It seems to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/fyvrxeLw/

Comment: What output are you getting instead, and what result do you expect?